# cabal install accelerate-cuda error with Mac OS X

Tags: macos, haskell, cuda, cabal

I'm trying to install accelerate-cuda module on Mac OS X (10.7.5).
I installed cuda module manually ([Error installing cuda module in Mac OS X 10.7.5 (checking whether the C compiler works… no)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20603001/error-installing-cuda-module-in-mac-os-x-10-7-5-checking-whether-the-c-compiler)) as I couldn't use cabal.

I have this error message with `cabal install accelerate-cuda`.

```
…
[34 of 34] Compiling Data.Array.Accelerate.CUDA.Foreign ( Data/Array/Accelerate/CUDA/Foreign.hs, dist/build/Data/Array/Accelerate/CUDA/Foreign.o )

Data/Array/Accelerate/CUDA/AST.hs:33:18:
    Could not find module `Foreign.CUDA.Analysis'
    Perhaps you haven't installed the profiling libraries for package `cuda-0.5.1.1'?
```

How to add the profiling libraries for package cuda?

Comment: 'What might be wrong?' seems to be exactly the question the error message is trying to answer. There are probably more possible answers, but you could at least check this one out first.

Comment: Perhaps you haven't installed the profiling libraries for package `cuda-0.5.1.1'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some hidden issues.

1. Enable library-profiling:True in ~/.cabal/config.
2. Download the source from http://hackage.haskell.org/package/accelerate

Then I needed to recompile some of the modules with `cabal install -p X --force-reinstalls --reinstall` where X is the upgrade necessary modules

With all these changes, `cabal install` solved the issues.